# How to read power consumption using CUPTI?

Tags: cuda, papi

I know that there's a way to read the power consumption of a GPU using CUPTI. Do you know of any method I can use? and where I can find examples?

Answer (score 5):

Probably what you are looking for is the cupti [ActivityEnvironment](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/structCUpti__ActivityEnvironment.html#structCUpti__ActivityEnvironment) data.

As far as I know, this particular data category is new in CUDA 5.5, so you may need to be sure you are using CUDA 5.5 to access these parameters.

Collecting this data is part of the cupti [Activity API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/r_main.html#r_activity)

An example of the usage of this API is given in the `activity_trace_async` example that is included in the CUPTI toolkit.

On a standard linux install, this sample would be located at `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/sample/activity_trace_async`

Comment: The enum `CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_ENVIRONMENT` does seem to be working. I get `CUPTI_ERROR_NOT_COMPATIBLE` for most of the `CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_*` not present in `activity_trace_async` when I call `cuptiActivityEnable()` api. Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA Management Library (NVML)[1](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml) is an API that allows you to read the power consumption of the GPU among other information.

It has C and python bindings.